# Post Json array in url

Tags: php, json, url

Is it possible to pass JSON in a URL?

For example, I have an array:

```
data = {  
  "name": "test",
  "user_id": 1
}
```

I want to pass it in to a URL like:

```
http://example.com/jsonArray
```

Comment: data is not an array in your case, it's a JSON object. Why not using POST method to send your data object ?

Comment: Yeah you can but why on earth would you want this? This is what POST requests are for :)

Comment: can't use post method as have to make a specific url to call api.

Comment: Maybe take a look at graphql api which seems more adapted than rest for what you want to do

Comment: worked with post requests and its working, but our task was to make a specific url to call an api.

Comment: You can stringify it and send it as a string, JSON.stringify(j);

Answer (score 2):

You should better use POST to pass such type of data, but, absolutely you could make a :

`$str = serialize(json_decode($data, true));`

And then pass you $str in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send the JSON array directly, but you can prepare it in a way that allows it to be sent to your API. You turn your JSON into a string and encode it so it will be properly formatted for a GET.

```
// your JSON data
var data = '{"name":"Homer Simpson","status":"Suspended","disciplinary-dates":["2018-01-2","2018-02-14","2018-03-17"]}' ;

// take your JSON, turn it into a string and then encode it 
var urlParams = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)) ;

// your URL adding your JSON data as the value
var url = 'http://example.com/?params=' + urlParams ;
```

On the PHP side you will decode

```
  // note: this code does not have any error checking - you should add it      
  // get your params
  $params = $_GET['params'] ;

  // decode the string
  $decodedParams = urldecode($params) ;

  // turn your string into an array
  $wasJSONAsArray = json_decode($decodedParams, true) ;

  // turn your string into a std object
  $wasJSONAsStdObj = json_decode($decodedParams) ;
```